# SQL query for fetching rows in certain language (with default lang)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with cities:

- city_id
- name
- languagecode

Sample data (city_id, name, languagecode):

- 1, LondonName, en
- 1, LondonName, de
- 1, LondonName123, jp
- 2, Barcelona, en
- 2, Barcelona123, de,
- 3, Madrid, en

How can I fetch all cities in certain language (i.e. de), but if there there aren't city translation in that language I want fetch translation in default language (i.e. english) for this row.

So, result for languagecode "de" should be like this:

- 1, LondonName, de
- 2, Barcelona123, de
- 3, Madrid, en

Database: MySQL

Comment: may be this can work Select * from cities where languagecode='de' OR (languagecode != 'de' AND languagecode='en').

Comment: @Ravin: your attempt will not show what the OP asks for. It will show both "de" and "en" rows.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer to use JOIN rather than inner select, so here's a second option:

```
SELECT c.city_id,
IF(c2.name IS NULL,c.name,c2.name) 'name',
IF(c2.languagecode IS NULL, c.languagecode, c2.languagecode) 'languagecode'
FROM cities c
LEFT JOIN cities c2 ON c.city_id = c2.city_id AND c2.languagecode = 'de'
WHERE c.languagecode = 'en'
GROUP BY c.city_id
```

Comment: +1 @Galz: Nice. You could use `COALESCE()` instead of `IF` and `IS NULL`.

Comment: @ypercube - correct, I need to add this function to my personal toolbox... :) Thanks!